# Im getting the error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm', or ''__attribute__' before 'void'

Tags: c, gcc, token

I am experiencing this error at my preprocessText() function (below) in my .c and I'm not entirely sure why. From browsing it seems most people were missing a { or ( or ; etc somewhere, but I'm fairly certain I am not.

```
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "Assembler.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   // ...
   preprocessText(file, inter1);
   // ...
}

public void preprocessText(FILE* file, FILE* file2) { //error happens at this declaration
    // ...
}
```

My header file is:

```
#ifndef ASSEMBLER_H
#define ASSEMBLER_H
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
// ...
void preprocessText(FILE* file, FILE* file2);
#endif
```

Comment: There is no public keyword in C

Comment: yeah I just realized this, thanks

Answer (score 2):

All methods are implicitly accessible by any other piece of code, if the function name is in scope. There is no `public` keyword in `c`

Answer (score 1):

You have 'public' before 'void'. Remember, this is C ;)